# Algorithm to beat Strassen's Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, strassen

Professor Caesar wishes to develop a matrix-multiplication algorithm that is
asymptotically faster than Strassen’s algorithm. His algorithm will use the divide and-conquer method, dividing each matrix into pieces of size n/4 x n/4, and the divide and combine steps together will take Theta(n^2) time.

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort in trying to solve this?

Comment: @ScottHunter I found this solution online but I didn't understand it. http://clrs.skanev.com/04/05/02.html

Comment: What solution?  I don't see any solution.

Comment: @ScottHunter I updated my reply with the link of the solution

Comment: Could you explain the question further? Are you asking for the pseudo code of an algorithm that is asymptotically faster than Strassen's matrix multiplication algorithm? Should the algorithm also use divide and conquer that has a combination step that take theta(n^2) time? Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really specify what the question is here, but I guess it is to disprove that this trivial algorithm runs faster than Strassen.

Say you divide your matrices into  blocks each of dimension *(n / k) X (n / k)* (in your question, *k* is 4). Then each matrix will have *k<sup>2</sup>* blocks, and there will be *k<sup>3</sup>* block multiplications (each block in the first matrix will be multiplied by *k* blocks in the second matrix). Consequently, the complexity recurrence is

*T(n) = k<sup>3</sup> T(n / k) + Θ(n<sup>2</sup>)*.

By [case 1 of the Master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem#Generic_form_2), this implies

*T(n) = Θ(n<sup>log<sub>k</sub>(k<sup>3</sup>)</sup>) = Θ(n<sup>3</sup>)*.

This is the same as ordinary matrix multiplication. It does not beat Strassen, obviously.

Comment: "divide your matrices into k blocks ... each matrix will have k^2 blocks"?

Comment: @ScottHunter Many thanks!  That was a horrible typo.

Comment: No, it was a brilliant typo :)